# How to use GYP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, gyp

I am trying to build [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/src) to a visual studio project using [GYP](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/).

The JCEF download includes all the C++ files and .gyp, .gypi files.

I have no experience in Python and wonder how I run the actual .gyp file so it turns into a visual studio project?

I have downloaded the gyp source, then ran the command 'gclient sync' in cmd to install python and download other tools. I could only find tools to improve visual studio project layout. What is the command to actually run the .gyp file?

Comment: I have downloaded the gyp source, then ran the command 'gclient sync' in cmd to install python and download other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For building visual studio projects you can use gyp like this

```
gyp <your gyp filename> -DOS=win --depth=. -f msvs -G msvs_version=2013 --generator-output=./build_win -Icommon.gypi
```

gyp is the gyp.bat present in the gyp download. VS project will be created in build_win directory, generator-output lets you specify where you want the projects generated. -I is used to add any gyp include files, in this example common.gypi is getting included, replace it with your appropriate gypi file